# Google app engine backend with android client

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am trying to learn how to develop android apps with cloud storage using Google App Engine.

I have gone trough several tutorials and managed to create an app and deployed it to app engine.

The trouble is , i cant access the backend from my android device(when i run the app using android phone).

I keep getting rrror 404, not found.

Perhaps some settings missing?

Here is the error generated by the code .

```
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135): 404 Not Found
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135): Not Found
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135): Not Found
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.example.dailyinspirations.MainActivity$AddQuoteAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:92)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at com.example.dailyinspirations.MainActivity$AddQuoteAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:216)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:337)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:169)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1119)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
04-26 21:02:55.228: D/Could not Add Quote(10135):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
```

Any pointers to what might be  wrong?

Ronald